# Do I really need to close the file? If so, why and how?

Tags: python

The code was taken from "Learn Python The Hard Way" exercise 17 but I've tweaked with it a bit, so hence I'm asking the question:

---

```
from sys import argv
from os.path import exists

script, file1, file2 = argv

print "Copying from %s to %s:" % (file1, file2)

indata = open(file1).read()

print "The input file is %d bytes long" % len(indata)

print "Does the output file exist? %r" % exists(file2)

outdata = open(file2, 'w').write(indata)
```

---

When i add the lines:

```
file1.close()
file2.close()
```

at the end of this code. I get the output on terminal:

Copying from python/test.txt to python/sampleout.txt:

```
The input file is 18 bytes long
Does the output file exist? True
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python/myprogram0.py", line 16, in <module>
    file1.close()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'close'
```

---

The code works fine without those two lines. But I thought I'd ask anyway.

So what am I doing wrong here? and what does that last bit mean?

Comment: I recommend giving `file1` and `file2` more appropriate names, such as `input_file_name` and `output_file_name`.

Answer (score 8):

You are not closing the file, but trying to "close" the filename, which is a string. What you need to do is to save the return value of the `open(...)` in a variable, and call `close` on it:

```
infile = open(file1)
indata = infile.read()
infile.close()
```

Instead of calling `close` explicitly, in modern code it is preferable to use the `with` statement; when the with statement is exited, either because the code run to completion, or because an exception was thrown, the file is closed automatically:

```
from sys import argv
from os.path import exists

script, input_file_name, output_file_name = argv

print("Copying from {} to {}:".format(input_file_name, output_file_name))

with open(input_file_name) as input_file:
    data = input_file.read()

print("The input file is {} bytes long".format(len(data)))
print("Does the output file exist? {}".format(exists(output_file_name)))

with open(output_file_name, 'w') as output_file:
    output_file.write(data)
```

Comment: The `with` keyword will also ensure the file is closed if an error is encountered in the indented code after it, not just if execution went well. More specifically, it ensures `__enter__` and `__exit__` are called for the given [context manager](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers).

Answer (score 1):

you need to do this :

```
  indata = open(file1)
  mystring = indata.read()
  indata.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

file1 and file2 in your case are strings, to close the files use the file descriptors:

```
indata.close()
outdata.close()
```

Reade here about file manipulations in Python: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html
In general Python closes the files implicitly once tit's filedescriptor becomes out of the scope. Please read [this](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/python-variable-scope-notes/) about Python's variable scope.

Comment: Neither `indata` nor `outdata` are file objects or file descriptors.  `indata` is a string, and `outdata` is `None`.

Comment: Still get this error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python/myprogram0.py", line 16, in <module>
    indata.close(file1)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'close'

Answer (score 0):

That is because the **file1** and **file2** variables are strings not file descriptors, first store the file descriptor in a variable and the close it after you use it.

```
f1 = open(file1)
# Read the contents of the file
f1.close()
```

The same applies for the **file2** variable. You should use the **with** statement because the file is closed automatically after the with block.

```
with open(file1) as f1:  # The file1 is open
    indata = f1.read()
    with open(file2) as f2:  # The file2 is open
        # The file1 and file2 will be automatically closed after the next line
        f2.write(indata)
```

When you open a file you get a file descriptor that is basically an index in a structure held by the kernel that stores the reference for all the open files, so when you finish to use the file you need to close it the remove that reference. To process uses the file descriptor to access the file, the process has to pass the file descriptor to the kernel through a system call and the kernel will access the file on behalf of the process.